# Bootstrap accordion unfold while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make the accordion which is shown below in the code in a way that all are unfolding while the user is scrolling down. At the moment only the first is unfold and the other are going to be unfold, when the user clicks the headline. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h1 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              A
            </button>
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              B
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
           Text
           <ul>Darum</ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              C
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
              D
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingFive">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
              E
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .is(':visible') and create a loop for each accordion item.

For example: if $('#headingFour').is(':visible') then trigger click on $('#headingFour button')!